# extract data from nested List

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, list

**The Code:**

```
List<Expense> exp = new List<Expense>();
List<Budget> bud = new List<Budget>();

     bud.Add(new Budget()
     {
         sal_tp = 0,
         sal_fos_veri = 1
     });


     exp.Add(new Expense()
       {
             sal_tp =2,                                             
             sal_fos_veri = 3                            
       });
bud.Add(new Budget()
     {
         sal_tp = 4,
         sal_fos_veri = 5
     });


     exp.Add(new Expense()
       {
             sal_tp =6,                                             
             sal_fos_veri = 7                            
       });


bud.Add(new Budget()
     {
         sal_tp = 8,
         sal_fos_veri = 9
     });


     exp.Add(new Expense()
       {
             sal_tp =10,                                             
             sal_fos_veri = 11                            
       });


bud.Add(new Budget()
     {
         sal_tp = 12,
         sal_fos_veri = 13
     });


     exp.Add(new Expense()
       {
             sal_tp =14,                                             
             sal_fos_veri = 15                            
       });


bud.Add(new Budget()
     {
         sal_tp = 16,
         sal_fos_veri = 17
     });


     exp.Add(new Expense()
       {
             sal_tp =18,                                             
             sal_fos_veri = 19                            
       });


bud.Add(new Budget()
     {
         sal_tp = 20,
         sal_fos_veri = 21
     });


     exp.Add(new Expense()
       {
             sal_tp =22,                                             
             sal_fos_veri = 23                            
       });


bud.Add(new Budget()
     {
         sal_tp = 24,
         sal_fos_veri = 25
     });


     exp.Add(new Expense()
       {
             sal_tp =26,                                             
             sal_fos_veri = 27                            
       });
```

***end of partial class***

```
public class Expense
                    {
                        public int sal_tp { get; set; }
                        public int sal_fos_veri { get; set; }
                    }
            public class Budget
                {
                    public int sal_tp { get; set; }
                    public int sal_fos_veri { get; set; }
                  }
```

**expecting ouput like:**

**0      2      1     4    3    5  .... and so on.... **

> how to iterate both the lists at a time? I have tried something like
>   this

```
for(int i=0;i<bud.Count;i++)
{
                       Expense explist=exp[i];
                       Budget budlist=bud[i];
                       Response.Write(budlist.sal_tp);
                       Response.Write(explist.sal_tp);
                       Response.Write(budlist.sal_fos_veri);
                       Response.Write(explist.sal_fos_veri);
 }
```

**problem:** this will increase code, I want to iterate through that "budlist" also. Like i used to do something like this in java

```
for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++)
       {
          for(int j=0;j<((ArrayList)data.get(i)).size();j++)
           {
               out.print("<td>");
               out.print(((ArrayList)data.get(i)).get(j));
               out.print("</td>");
               out.print("<td>"+((ArrayList)exp_data.get(i)).get(j)+"</td>");
           }
           out.println("</tr>");
       }
```

Is anything like that possible?

Comment: You can do exactly the same thing in C#. What's the problem with that?

Comment: Not related to your question, but you shouldn't use variable names like `bud`, because they are confusing. Write full words.

Comment: +1 to comments above. Other than that, you can give [Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/dd267698.aspx) a shot if you feel fancy.

Comment: I'm really confused. You do not have a nested list. And I don't see how does that snippet “increase code”.

Comment: k guys i have edited, now thats just example, here I have much data above 100 +

Comment: If i could directly access by index like bud[0][0], how to do that?

Comment: @svick is it nested list now?? I too really dont know, but I am  in this situation now.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to extract common abstraction as

```
public interface  IMoneyTransaction
{
    int sal_tp { get; set; }
    int sal_fos_veri { get; set; }
}
```

Your class declaration would change a little bit:

```
public class Expense : IMoneyTransaction
{
    public int sal_tp { get; set; }
    public int sal_fos_veri { get; set; }
}

public class Budget : IMoneyTransaction
{
    public int sal_tp { get; set; }
    public int sal_fos_veri { get; set; }
}
```

Filling the lists as:

```
var exp = new List<IMoneyTransaction>{
    new Budget
    {
        sal_tp = 0,
        sal_fos_veri = 1
    }};

var bud = new List<IMoneyTransaction>{
    new Expense
    {
        sal_tp =2,                                             
        sal_fos_veri = 3                            
    }};
```

Now you can use `Union` to merge data and iterate over it using one common interface

```
var allItems = exp.Union(bud).ToArray();

for(int i = 0; i < allItems.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine (allItems[i].sal_fos_veri);
    Console.WriteLine (allItems[i].sal_tp);
}
```

Comment: I would have taken this advice, but what is allItems are many say in 100's. then i have to access each element in it wright? Can i loop through allItems also? If so how?

Comment: you **are** looping through `allItems` in the loop given above

Comment: See here as an example I gave only to elements, what if I have many elements, like sal_fos_veri,ab,cd,ef,gh,ij,kl,mn,bv,ed,th,uj...... then i have to write  allItems[i].sal_fos_veri + allItems[i].ab + allItems[i].cd   +  allItems[i].ef ..... and soo on, which i dont want to do

Comment: these are not elements, but properties. How else can you specify logic of addition, without writing it out? You can add high-level aggregate method to interface and realize it in subclasses. Use simple and straight `OOP` approaches.

Comment: oh i see, i was scratching my head for soo long, those are properties.. :) and that i dint write as addition, it was just to show, as you have seen in ques, that comes in Response.Write();, Still is there any way to get properties one by one? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `one by one`? Can you please explain it in more detail.